# Bash script: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, unexpected-token

I have the following piece of code:

```
function sindex {  
    x="${1%%$2*}"
    [[ $x = $1 ]] && echo -1 || echo ${#x}
}

T_ID_INDEX=$(sindex "$TARGET_RETURN" "id=")  
T_ID_INDEX=$((T_ID_INDEX + 4))  
T_ID=${TARGET_RETURN:T_ID_INDEX:36}
```

And i am getting the following error:

```
line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have try to add 'done' and 'fi' at the end of the code as well as adding ' ; ' at the end of the brackets {}, but nothing has worked.

Comment: "unexpected end of life"? Perhaps someone died? Better show us the complete script.

Comment: my mistake "unexpected end of file"

Comment: Is line 7 what looks like line 7 in your code?

Comment: line 7 is a blank line, right after the last line up above.

Comment: for the above it should be line 9. ill fix that. my bad

Comment: Does your script have DOS line endings? I think that would prevent the `}` from being recognized as the end of the function definition.

Comment: You only have 8 lines. How can the complaint be on line 9? Perhaps you should perform a `cat -n <my_script.sh>`.

Comment: clean your script with `dos2unix myScript`. Also, learn to use and fix errors at https://shellcheck.net before posting Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: It runs without error for me.